# Are JSP and Servlet container same?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I like to know JSP and Servlet container are same?
Which are they?
Is only one container responsible for calling Service methods of both?
Than why do we call Jsp container and Servlet container?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSPs are servlets. So a servlet container is a JSP container.