# jsp container vs servlet container

Tags: servlet-container

I am studying about servlet technology in which I heared the term servlet container and jsp container, I am getting confused that both are same or not.
A jsp page is handlded by jsp container but servlet is handled by servlet container.
On searching some site I found in servlet container there is a file called **page compiler** which turns servlet container into jsp contaner when a jsp request comes.

So I want to know, actually the conversion happens between these tow or both are the same things which is used interchangebly.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate!! Similar question has already been answered.Refer to link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113934/are-jsp-and-servlet-container-same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there is no such thing as a JSP container which is not a Servlet container because a JSP is translated into Servlet before it is executed. So a JSP container must support Servlet.

The opposite is not always true, at least in the old times when Servlet technology first came into existence and the container was called Servlet container.

When JSP came out, an engine that interprets and processes JSP pages into a servlet is added to the old Servlet container and people usually call such a container JSP/Servlet container. Nowadays, JSP container and Servlet container more or less mean the same thing because they both support JSP and Servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Jsp and servelet are interchangeable. As wit serverlet , jsp excute as part of a web server. The server component that executes them is reffered as jsp container.